# .net w2012 r2 custom error 404 not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, webforms, web-config

This web.config code works perfectly under w2003 .net 4:

```xml
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="error-notfound.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

On a w2012 r2 .net 4 the code DOESN'T WORK: I got no erros but when calling a page not found, IIS shows 404.htm located in C:\inetpub\custerr\en-US, not error-notfound.aspx as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating the same error rules in the system.webServer section of the web.config file, for example...

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/error-notfound.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```